# Vlookup/Match - Reference external workbook array in a cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vlookup

This probably isn’t possible but is there a way of referencing a cell that contains a workbook , name , location , tab and range when using Vlookup and Match formulas ?

I have a lot of references to other workbooks but I want to keep track of all the workbooks via one location

Im using the Northwind table as an example

https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCEQFjAAahUKEwilut7YxuXHAhUta9sKHWr-CV4&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.exceldashboard.org%2FNorthwind.xls&usg=AFQjCNGnhABr44N7nhF6oa5qtH9U930p0w&bvm=bv.102022582,d.d24

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This should be possible using INDIRECT function. Here you can find how to use it to reference other workbook

http://www.contextures.com/xlFunctions05.html

unfortunately the function does not work if the source workbook is closed, but you can use Morefunc addin to use INDIRECT.EXT function which can reference closed workbook. Some info about it here:

http://www.ashishmathur.com/tag/indirect-ext/

http://download.cnet.com/Morefunc/3000-2077_4-10423159.html